# Functions to convert SQL into VBA strings

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I construct hundreds of SQL Queries in an excel sheet and each one is placed in a cell of 1 column. What I am looking to do is run each of these SQL statements from excel.

Just wondering if anyone knows a way to convert all my SQL into VBA Strings to that I can loop through all rows to run each query.

I found this which is what I want to do but is there a way I can alter the code so it can read off excel cells rather than a Form?

http://allenbrowne.com/ser-71.html

Thanks

EDIT: Here is a sample SQL that I am trying to convert

```
SELECT 
TT.TEST_TABLE_ID,
TT.TEST_TABLE_NO,
TT.MEMBERSHIP_NUMBER,
TT.TEST_TABLE_TYPE,
from TEST_TABLE TT
```

I think because each Select is in its own line it causes problems when it converts.

EDIT #2: Here is my code that executes SQL

```
Sub GetData()
Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim RS As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim sqlText As String
Dim Row As Long
Dim Findex As Long
Dim Data As Worksheet
Dim X As Long
    Set Data = Sheets("Results")
    Data.Select
    Cells.ClearContents
    Conn.Open "PROVIDER=ORAOLEDB.ORACLE;DATA SOURCE=ORCL;USER ID=user;PASSWORD=password"
    cmd.ActiveConnection = Conn
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
    'sqlText = How to reference Valid SQL cells
    cmd.CommandText = sqlText
    Set RS = cmd.Execute
    For X = 1 To RS.Fields.Count
        Data.Cells(1, X) = RS.Fields(X - 1).Name
    Next

    If RS.RecordCount < Rows.Count Then
        Data.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset RS
    Else
        Do While Not RS.EOF
           Row = Row + 1
           For Findex = 0 To RS.Fields.Count - 1
             If Row >= Rows.Count - 50 Then
                Exit For
             End If
             Data.Cells(Row + 1, Findex + 1) = RS.Fields(Findex).Value
           Next Findex
           RS.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

in the SQL text part I want to be able to reference my column of SQL statements that I have. I thought I needed to convert it but you guys are right that if referencing it I can Just use your code Brad.

I tried to incorporate your code brad where my  'sqlText = How to reference Valid SQL cells is but had no success

Comment: Do you already have quotes at start and end?

Comment: No I do not, but I can add if its easier

Comment: If you can copy the SQL from one of your cells and run it in a query tool, there is no need for any additional formatting, just read the SQL from the cell and execute it directly in your VBA. If you think there is some additional formatting required, you should explain exactly what it is, and provide examples.  The link you posted is about *including SQL in VBA source code*, and is not required just to *execute* that SQL.  From your current post, @Brad's answer already provides a solution.

Comment: Yes sorry thats where I was not clear. I have a Valid SQL statement, and I am trying to execute this SQL statement in VBA Source code which requires formatting changes

Comment: Are you expecting to have data returned to you? There is a difference between executing (I was expecting to see a bunch of `inserts/updates/deletes`) and returning records for you to use (`selects`). When you execute the code you provided what happens and why is it wrong?

Comment: Yes, I am expecting to have the results returned to me. No inserts/updates/deletes its more of a verification to see if the data exists so just selects

Comment: Where are you putting the results? I think your code is working just not complete. Do you have a recordset object right now? Post the code which executes your queries if you can. Just executing a `select` will do nothing unto itself.

Comment: Since you say you have hundreds of `SELECT`s are you expecting to end up with hundreds or worksheets? How do you know where to place each query? Are you only executing one at a time? i.e. only a chosen query gets plopped into the `Results` sheet?

Comment: no, each select is only going to return 1 row of data. So beside each select I was going to return the results or blank if no results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a start to the code I think you need.

I have placed the SQL in a sheet named "SQL", in Col A.
The issues with this are: 
(1) You are placing field names in a row, then the data that is returned into a row. That will require two rows per SQL statement.
(2) I copied the SQL statement from sheet "SQL' and placed in Col A of "Results" (you mentioned you wanted to place results to right of SQL String. (3) You clear the contents of "Results" sheet, so you need to be careful not to erase your SQL if you decide to combine sheets.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Process_SQL_Strings()
Dim cmd         As New ADODB.Command
Dim sqlText     As String
Dim Row         As Long
Dim Findex      As Long
Dim Data        As Worksheet
Dim iFldCt      As Long
Dim conn        As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs          As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConn       As String
Dim lLastRow    As Long
Dim lRow        As Long

    Set Data = Sheets("Results")
    Data.Select
    Cells.ClearContents
    conn.Open "PROVIDER=ORAOLEDB.ORACLE;DATA SOURCE=ORCL;USER ID=user;PASSWORD=password"
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
    cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

''        Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
''        sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
''                                 "Data Source=C:\data\access\tek_tips.accdb;" & _
''                                 "Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;" & _
''                                 "Persist Security Info=False;"
    conn.Open sConn

    'sqlText = How to reference Valid SQL cells
    lRow = 1
    Do
        sqlText = Sheets("SQL").Range("A" & lRow)
        If sqlText = "" Then
            MsgBox "Finished processing " & lRow & " rows of SQL", vbOKOnly, "Finished"
            GoTo Wrap_Up
        End If

        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
        rs.Open sqlText, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic, adCmdText

        Data.Cells(lRow, 1) = sqlText

       If not rs.EOF then
        For iFldCt = 1 To rs.Fields.Count
            Data.Cells(lRow, 1 + iFldCt) = rs.Fields(iFldCt - 1).Name
        Next

        If rs.RecordCount < Rows.Count Then
            Data.Range("B" & lRow).CopyFromRecordset rs
        Else
            Do While Not rs.EOF
               Row = Row + 1
               For Findex = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
                 If Row >= Rows.Count - 50 Then
                    Exit For
                 End If
                 Data.Cells(Row + 1, Findex + 1) = rs.Fields(Findex).value
               Next Findex
               rs.MoveNext
            Loop
        End If
        Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
      End If
        lRow = lRow + 1
    Loop
Wrap_Up:
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: doesn't look like any of the strSql = "strSql = """ & strSql & """" got added, the double of quotes got added when looking at debug

Comment: might be something with Replace(strSql, vbCrLf, strcLineEnd)?

Comment: Are you trying to take a VALID SQL string and convert to a 'string' that can be executed? Or are you trying to parse a SQL string into multiple lines of VBA code with continuation lines? I took string (ignore the |)  |SELECT Table1.*, Table1.FldA FROM Table1 WHERE (((Table1.FldA)="A1"));| and it converted to |strSql = "SELECT Table1.*, Table1.FldA FROM Table1 WHERE (((Table1.FldA)=""A1""));"|

Comment: Yes - I am trying to take a valid SQL string and convert it to a string that can be executed via VBA..sorry for the confusion

Comment: @JohnJones Can you post an example f what query is not currently working? Depending on what kind of DB you are running against you can replace double quotes with single quotes. Then there is none of this escaping business.

Comment: I added a line to answer so it saves SQL in Col B. Please share a SQL string that you think does not get converted. The code produces 'strSQL' which can be executed by VBA.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Hey Wayne, I figured out the issue but I am not sure how to fix it. The Valid SQL String that is being converted is a line for each Select Statement (I edited my question to show an example). When it gets converted each select is still in its own line which is not the proper format to be executed in VBA...see my code above

Comment: Yeah, I just looked at your sample - is what you posted all in ONE cell, or spread over six rows?  If I paste your example into Excel, it is spread over six rows. It makes a big difference!

Comment: It is all in one cell, I have hundreds of these select statements in a column individually contained in its own cell.

Comment: Ahhh, I think I get your point. First, is the converted SQL string correct? I think the answer is YES. Is what you want is to have |strsql = "xxxx"| |db.execute strsql |?

Comment: Hey Wayne...I realized that I can  just read the SQL from the cell and execute it directly in my VBA, no formatting needed..the above is only required if i want SQL in my VBA source code which is not needed. I just want to be able to execute my selects that are all in one column. SEe my edit #2

Comment: I am modifying your code to produce what you want - basically you need to loop through all the SQL strings - and will update my answer.

Comment: Yes, to provide additional information All my SQL strings are in one column and each string will return 1 row of data, so I was going to place the results starting with the column to the right of my SQL string

Comment: You are clearing all content in the Results sheet. Either you need to place results to right of 'SQL' sheet, or change the code to not clear col A.

Comment: Also, you are pasting the field names in columns, then pasting data below that. That requires TWO rows per SQL string processed.  Will all queries produce the same field names?

Comment: Hey Wayne, thanks for updated Answer. To address your issues 1) Is there a way for me to not return the field headings? I think I will just use 1 sheet, have my SQL statements in col A, results in B so I will need to get rid of my clear sheets. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Also can you explain your commented out NEW ADODB Conneciton? Right now I get a Object Variable or With Block variable not set in my conn.Open line

Comment: Hey Wayne, to solve the above I set Dim conn        As New ADODB.Connection and
Dim rs          As New ADODB.Recordset and removed the conn.Open sConn

Comment: My bad... I don't have Oracle so your connection would not work for me, so I used an Access database I have.  I should have commented out "conn.Open sConn", so please do that.  Also, yes, you can avoid pasting the headers -- actually my code just writes over them with the fields returned from the query. If all column names are the same from all queries, you could make row 1 for headers (would need to adjust code to select 2nd row as being the first containing sql)

Comment: Thanks Wayne...actually each query will have different headings but the purpose of me running this is just to see if I get any result back from my select (my select statement is extremely specific and It will only return 1 row max). Everything is working great just one question when my query returns no results it returns the column headings which isnt the worst thing but can I return no results instead?

Comment: I just updated code and added 'If not rs.EOF Then' and closed the 'If' just after 'Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit'

Comment: This is great Wayne, thanks I ended up just placing it all in one sheet instead of placing the results in "Results" Sheet. Just one other thing that crossed my mind. If I want to ensure that only 1 record is returned what is the best way to incorporate that. Its not a valid scenario but there is a small chance it may occur or at least I should check for it. Right now the next select statement will overwrite that extra row. Since I setup my select statements all within one column I was thinking that I would need to insert a row if more than 1 record was returned is that possible to add?

Comment: To insure ONLY 1 row returned "Select Top 1 ...". To test for more than 1, after opening RS: | RS.MoveLast | RS.MoveFirst | Debug.Print RS.Recordcount |

Answer (score 0):

I am using something this:

```
Function SQLQueryRun(ByVal query As String, ByVal returnData As Boolean) As Variant
Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim ADODBCmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim ret As New ADODB.Recordset

    Conn.ConnectionString = "connection_string_here"
    Conn.Open
    ADODBCmd.ActiveConnection = Conn
    ADODBCmd.CommandText = query
    Set ret = ADODBCmd.Execute()
    If returnData Then
        If Not ret.EOF Then SQLQueryRun = ret.GetRows()
    Else
        SQLQueryRun = True
    End If
    Conn.Close
    Set Conn = Nothing
    Set ret = Nothing
End Function
```

If the second argument is `False` nothing is returned by function. Are you expecting results from query run?

 Also I use a macro to create Query/Pivot table from sql contained in windows clipboard, if you are interested let me know.

Comment: Thanks but my main issue is the conversion of my SQL Select to VBA, ive already been able to run queries off of my DB via VBA Im just trying to get it in the right VBA notation

Comment: What do you exactly mean by conversion SQL to VBA ?

Comment: if you have SQL there is no conversion necessary. the queries are not "running in VBA". VBA is just facilityating the execution of that SQL somewhere else. SQL is SQL.

Comment: Sorry maybe conversion isnt the right word but in order to run the query on VBA, it needs to be formatted in a certain way. If you go to my link provide you'll see he needs to change the string inorder to run on VBA

Comment: Are your queries contained in one Excel row?

Comment: Do you need these queries to bie formatted human readable in VBA? There is no need to format this for ODBC (tested on ms sql server). Valid query contained in a single line works.

Comment: Yes - all contained in one column. Each within its own cell. I am trying to  execute this SQL statement in VBA Source code which requires formatting changes (ex. There is a character limit in VBA for each line)

Comment: @Avb, I think the concern *maybe* is if one VBA line exceeds ~1020 characters - thus a large query has to be split into multiple continuation lines... ???

Comment: @Wayne: I cannot check this now, but I produce queries that surely exceed 1k characters and no error ever occured. But you may be right, I did not try this with ADODB straight, but through Excel's PivotCache (which looks quite similar). I will check this tomorrow at work.

Comment: @avb, I think we helped get this straight now. I thought at one time the OP wanted to generate a line of VBA code containing the actual SQL -- which may have been longer than 1K for ONE line of uncontinued-code. Yes, I agree with you that you can exceed 1K for a query in VBA, but you need to break the continued-lines into < 1K.

Comment: @Wayne, just checked this, 4566 chars in single string executed with `ADODB.Command`, works.

Comment: @avb, I think we are saying the same thing... I too have used queries >4000 char. I was thinking OP possibly wanted only ONE line - uncontinued. So I created VBA line: debug.print len("aaaa") then kept replacing every 'a' with a bunch... when I got around ~1024 I got a 'Line Too Long' error in VBA (then I could have continued the line) Thanks!

Comment: @Wayne silly me :), all the time you meant VBA line length not SQL, which I meant.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a connection to your database and loop through all the cells and execute your code in each cell.

You can use ADO to to make the connection (need to add a reference to `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library`)

You'll need to figure out your [connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/), open a connection, then loop through all the cells and execute the SQL in those cells.

```
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim connectionString As String
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim c As Range, ws As Worksheet
Dim rst as ADODB.Recordset

connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=C:\Database3.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
cnn.Open connectionString
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn

For Each c In ws.Range()
    cmd.CommandText = c.Value
    set rst = cmd.Execute 
    'do what you need to with your new recordset before moving on to the next SELECT
Next c
```

Comment: Thanks but my main issue is the conversion of my SQL Select to VBA

Comment: @JohnJones I updated to include returning a recordset

Comment: Hey Bard - Let me update my question to include my code so far.